# Replace string with text typed in by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

i couldnt get it to work on jsfiddle so i'll just paste the working site here: http://fariskassim.com/stage/simplified/

So i have a sentence loading on random within the div #randomname, on page refresh or when a user clicks on the button 'Generate'.

In each of the sentence in the array, there are the words 'AGENCY NAME' and 'BRAND NAME' that i wish to replace with text that is typed in by a user in the input field available.

Currently what i've managed to do is to replace 'AGENCY NAME' and 'BRAND NAME' with this

```
function replaceName1() {
var str = document.getElementById("randomname").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("AGENCY NAME", "REPLACED AGENCY");
document.getElementById("randomname").innerHTML = res;
}
```

But i was hoping to be able to replace it more dynamically by typing into the form / input text box.

Comment: Are you looking to do this with jQuery on vanilla JS?

Comment: i'm not very familiar with that. umm is it possible with just javascript or maybe jquery without additional frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a global "replace all" function, you could do it this way:

```
function replaceName1() {
  var agencyName = document.getElementsByName("agency_name")[0].value;
  var brandName = document.getElementsByName("brand_name")[0].value;
  var str = document.getElementById("randomname").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace("AGENCY NAME", agencyName).replace("BRAND NAME", brandName);
  document.getElementById("randomname").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Make sure to replace "agency_name" and "brand_name" with the actual names of your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
<input onkeydown="replaceName1()">

function replaceName1() {
   var str = document.getElementById("randomname").innerHTML; 
   var res = str.replace("AGENCY NAME", "REPLACED AGENCY");
   document.getElementById("randomname").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Comment: i should be expecting the text in #randomname to change immediately when i start typing?

i didnt get this. but anyways the answer from mmichael got the job done for me. thanks!